# Zero Free Space on Centos 7 KVM

Tags: linux, centos, kvm, ext4, xfs

I have a number of Centos 7 KVM virtual machines running under proxmox.  Is there a way to ZERO out all unallocated space with zeros?  I have some that are EXT4 and some that are XFS.  Reason I want to do this is the weekly backups of entire KVM are compressed with gzip and they would be so much smaller if free space was zeroed.  I would also like to do this without disrupting the running KVM machine too much.

Comment: Make sure the VMs are sending discards all the way up.

Comment: Depending on where the command is being run, you could either use `fallocate` (see [fallocate man page][1]) or `fstrim` (see [fstrim man page][2]) to zero out the unused space in the filesystem.  


  [1]: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/fallocate.1.html "fallocate man page"
  [2]: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/fstrim.8.html "fstrim man page"